# "Destructive" jQuery shuffle problem

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Throughout, I am using [this jQuery shuffle pluggin](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-shuffle-plugin/).

This is the situation. I have a `<div class="masterDiv">` element containing many `<span class="toBeShuffled">` elements. Each `<span>` element contains a `<button>` element. My goal is to shuffle the buttons properly.

Now my code is the following:

```
$(".masterDiv").find(".toBeShuffled").shuffle();
```

which does indeed shuffle the `<span>` elements, and hence also the `<button>` elements.

My problem is that, using `.data()`, I have attached information to the `<button>` elements,  and this information disappears after the shuffle. How can I preserve the data I have attached?

Comment: It would be helpful with an example html with data attributes or maybe a jsfiddle example?

Comment: What is a goal of shuffling those elements? To get visual "shuffling", like in some game? Or you just need those elements in random order?

Comment: I need visual "shuffling", like in some game. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reattach `.data()` after `.shuffle()`-ing, or

use `.attr('data-something', 'value')`, or

use [html 5 custom data attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

Comment: Yuck. Don't like either approach.